# Is there any way to push the DPI limits when exporting a map from composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I noted that on OS X (El Capitan) running QGIS 2.18, I can't export map in A0 with a resolution higher than 340 dpi. If I try I receive an error message about possible memory overflows. I have 16GB of RAM on my machine so I don't think the limit is triggered by the OS.

I tested the same settings changing only the dpi. I noticed that I start getting a warning message about the memory usage at 121 dpi with a dialog box appearing just after clicking to export as jpg - `I start gettting the error at 121 dpi with message To create image 7622x8829 requires about 201 MB of memory. Proceed?`.

Even if I click on `OK`, I will then get an additional error box:

[image]

Is there any way around?

Comment: try dropping the dpi value to 150 or 200. Does it give you an estimated memory usage dialog instead, and if so, what values does it show?

Comment: Yes, if I set dpi to 150 I get a dialog box saying `To create image 9448x10945 requires about 310 MB of memory. Proceed?`

Comment: At 340 dpi (max I tested before getting the error) the same dialog box say `To create image 21417x24809 requires about 1594 MB of memory. Proceed?`

Comment: I start gettting the error at 121 dpi with message `To create image 7622x8829 requires about 201 MB of memory. Proceed?`

Comment: is this image to be printed on paper, or are you after an image to be displayed on-screen?

Comment: @StevenKay screen

Comment: Are you positive it is an *error* and not a *warning*? To me it looks like it offers the possibility to proceed.

Comment: found [this issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13186) which looks relevant.

Comment: @StevenKay I guess then the answer is no.

Comment: @Francesco can you confirm, that even if you click ok (and not cancel), no image is exported?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Yes, it cancels the job when I click OK